# how to install cpp man page on debian 10?

Tags: python, c++, pip, manpage

from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questaions/34507045/how-to-install-man-pages-for-c11 there is mentioned,

> cppman is no longer supported under Ubuntu/apt

and therefor no `libstdc++6-<version>-doc` could be install via `apt` anymore.

and the only way to install the man page is via `pip3`. So I have tried to install
`sudo apt-get install python-pip`  and `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`. Now, having `python3`, I can install it via `pip3`:
`pip3 install cppman`, everything seems correct, before I tried to cache the man pages: `cppman -c`, which giver error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/cppman", line 40, in <module>
    from cppman.main import Cppman
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cppman/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    import html
ImportError: No module named html
```

As could be seen, it uses `Python2.7` instead of `Python3`, that is strange.
From github, I have found similar problem here: https://github.com/aitjcize/cppman/issues/80, where they suggest to do

```
pip uninstall mancpp
pip3 install mancpp
```

Which I did, but when installing mancpp again from `pip3`, then another server error:

```
Collecting mancpp
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://pypi.org/simple/mancpp/
```

So what now? If you read till here, than you can see there are many errors, but cannot find solution anywhere in stack sites. I only want to have cpp manuals for searching for functions and classes (like std) and mainly for glibc++. As I could do simply with c functions. Why is it so hard? Anyway, how to install the mancpp via `pip3`?

`uname -a`:
`Linux 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: `pip (un)install mancpp` <- **cppman**, no?

Answer (score 0):

[The script](https://github.com/aitjcize/cppman/blob/master/bin/cppman) uses `#!/usr/bin/env python` shebang and on your system `python` is most probably 2.7. Just edit the script:

```
sudo vim /usr/local/bin/cppman
```

Append `3` at the end: `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and try again.